# Firebird error: cannot start transaction for password database

Tags: firebird

I am looking for some help - today my firebird database has stopped opening the database files with the following error:
engine code: 335544654
engine message: cannot start transaction for password database

I've tried googling but can't find any resources that have any relevant information.

Thanks

Comment: Check free disk space on root partition.

Comment: There is over 200GB free on the partition - thanks

Comment: Are you sure that is the full error message?

Answer (score 1):

I eventually got this resolved by doing a number of restores of the security2.fdb database.

Comment: A number of restores? A single one should have been sufficient.

Comment: Yes I thought the DB crashed on the 2nd but it actually crashed on the 1st so i had to do a second restore, but the restore was a restore from my server backup not a firebird restore.

Comment: I found the firebird log file and it said that the transaction log limit had exceeded and required backing up and restoring to reset it.  Does firebird not reset the transaction log when a backup is complete?  Does anyone have any steps on how to complete this task?

Comment: Firebird has no transaction log, it uses MVCC and records consists of multiple versions that are annotated with the transaction that created/updated/deleted the record. Once the transactiion counter exceeds its limit (2.5 and earlier 2^31 - 1, 2^48 for 3.0 and higher), the only way to currently reset the transaction counter is to backup **and** restore the backup.

Comment: Hi @MarkRotteveel yea i appreciate that, but the restore has never happened in our live production environment and i want to create a how-to guide on this so we can run it periodically throughout the year.  As I or any of the team have never performed a backup and restore using the correct method i was wondering if there was any guides that you could point me to on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Are you telling me you have never performed backup and restores, not even as disaster recovery rehearsal? In any case, look at the [Gbak - Firebird Backup & Restore Utility manual](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/user_manuals/html/gbak.html).

Comment: Nope, this is my first experience using Firebird as a production database (bear in mind i was just handed this to support, no by choice)  Thanks for your help Mark

Answer (score -1):

In my case, there was not enough data space in /var.
I cleared the contents of "/var/spool/clientmqueue/".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).